# Cannot read property 'fields' of undefined

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I'm new to ionic framework and trying to get all  contacts by using this plugin

```
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-contacts


 $scope.getAllContacts = function () {

            $cordovaContacts.find().then(function (allContacts) { //omitting parameter to .find() causes all contacts to be returned
            $scope.contacts = allContacts;

        });
    }
```

By executing the above code, I'm getting the error

```
 TypeError: Cannot read property 'fields' of undefined
```

Please help me, thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try defaulting the `$cordovaContacts.find()` method with an empty `[]` array like:

```
$cordovaContacts.find([]).then(function(allContacts) {
    $scope.contacts = allContacts;
});
```

Comment: After executing the above code, I 'm facing this issue "Cannot read property 'find' of undefined"

Comment: Have you injected ngCordova module like `angular.module('starter', ['ionic', 'ngCordova'])`? Did you inject the `$cordovaContacts` in the controller definition?